# Threebox GLTF Model partly wrong

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, gltf, threebox

I have an fbx model that i exportet as an embedded gltf in blender. When i load it into a map with threebox then it looks wrong but in the gltf viewer of threejs it looks right. What am i doing wrong?

[image: My Result in Threebox]

[image: GLTFViewer]

Some parts seem to work but some are completely white or partly transparent which is not in the original model and not in the GLTFViewer.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
const pokemonOptions = { obj: 'models/pokemon/beedrill/model.gltf', type: 'gltf', scale: 2, units: 'meters', rotation: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 } };

this.tb.loadObj(pokemonOptions, (model) => {
     model.setCoords([this.player.lng, this.player.lat]);
     this.tb.add(model);
});
```

And i also tried loading it with threejs manually but it still looks wrong.